# Converting a file to short array and vice versa

Tags: java, android, arrays, file

How can I read a `short` array from a file e.g. audio or video file? And how can I write it back to the file?

Comment: Use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt if **SHORT** if possible. Nevertheless, you can check out [Apache Commons File Utils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) for reading file as `byte[]` and vice verse.

```
public static byte[] readFileToByteArray(File file) throws IOException
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better example:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**  
 Converting binary data into different forms.

 <P>Reads binary data into memory, and writes it back out.
 (If your're actually copying a file, there are better ways to do this.)

 <P>Buffering is used when reading and writing files, to minimize the number 
 of interactions with the disk.
*/
public final class BytesStreamsAndFiles {

  /** Change these settings before running this class. */
  private static final String INPUT_FILE_NAME = "C:\\TEMP\\cottage.jpg";
  private static final String OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "C:\\TEMP\\cottage_copy.jpg";

  /** Run the example. */
  public static void main(String... aArgs) {
    BytesStreamsAndFiles test = new BytesStreamsAndFiles();
    //read in the bytes
    byte[] fileContents = test.read(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
    //test.readAlternateImpl(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
    //write it back out to a different file name
    test.write(fileContents, OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
  }

  /** Read the given binary file, and return its contents as a byte array.*/ 
  byte[] read(String aInputFileName){
    log("Reading in binary file named : " + aInputFileName);
    File file = new File(aInputFileName);
    log("File size: " + file.length());
    byte[] result = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    try {
      InputStream input = null;
      try {
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        while(totalBytesRead < result.length){
          int bytesRemaining = result.length - totalBytesRead;
          //input.read() returns -1, 0, or more :
          int bytesRead = input.read(result, totalBytesRead, bytesRemaining); 
          if (bytesRead > 0){
            totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;
          }
        }
        /*
         the above style is a bit tricky: it places bytes into the 'result' array; 
         'result' is an output parameter;
         the while loop usually has a single iteration only.
        */
        log("Num bytes read: " + totalBytesRead);
      }
      finally {
        log("Closing input stream.");
        input.close();
      }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      log("File not found.");
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      log(ex);
    }
    return result;
  }

  /**
   Write a byte array to the given file. 
   Writing binary data is significantly simpler than reading it. 
  */
  void write(byte[] aInput, String aOutputFileName){
    log("Writing binary file...");
    try {
      OutputStream output = null;
      try {
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(aOutputFileName));
        output.write(aInput);
      }
      finally {
        output.close();
      }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
      log("File not found.");
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
      log(ex);
    }
  }

  /** Read the given binary file, and return its contents as a byte array.*/ 
  byte[] readAlternateImpl(String aInputFileName){
    log("Reading in binary file named : " + aInputFileName);
    File file = new File(aInputFileName);
    log("File size: " + file.length());
    byte[] result = null;
    try {
      InputStream input =  new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
      result = readAndClose(input);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
      log(ex);
    }
    return result;
  }

  /**
   Read an input stream, and return it as a byte array.  
   Sometimes the source of bytes is an input stream instead of a file. 
   This implementation closes aInput after it's read.
  */
  byte[] readAndClose(InputStream aInput){
    //carries the data from input to output :    
    byte[] bucket = new byte[32*1024]; 
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = null; 
    try  {
      try {
        //Use buffering? No. Buffering avoids costly access to disk or network;
        //buffering to an in-memory stream makes no sense.
        result = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bucket.length);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while(bytesRead != -1){
          //aInput.read() returns -1, 0, or more :
          bytesRead = aInput.read(bucket);
          if(bytesRead > 0){
            result.write(bucket, 0, bytesRead);
          }
        }
      }
      finally {
        aInput.close();
        //result.close(); this is a no-operation for ByteArrayOutputStream
      }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
      log(ex);
    }
    return result.toByteArray();
  }

  private static void log(Object aThing){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(aThing));
  }
}
```

for more detail go to : [Reading and writing binary files](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245)

Answer (score -1):

The snippet below reads a file using FileInputStream, and writes the file to the given path using FileOutputStream.

Java Code:

```
byte[] fileBArray = new byte[(int)file.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fis.read(fileBArray);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\abc.jpg");
fos.write(fileBArray);
```